# Read only access to database, we want to SQL rows into ", " separated in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table in the below format:

```
Name     Department
sri       Dept1
nath      Dept2
shil      Dept1
```

I need an output in this format:

```
Dept1 - sri,shil
Dept2 - nath
```

The database is Oracle 11g. We have only read only access to the database. We want to collapse the rows into comma-separated lists, but the LISTAGG function has a 4000 character limit, and we cannot use PLSQL.

Comment: use to_clob that will convert into clob datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle's LISTAGG is the best option for this purpose. [This example](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=515) is very similar to what you're after. If you're hitting character limitations, try multiple passes, limiting the result set with, say, a regex:

```
--first pass: names starting with "A" through "P"
SELECT dept, LISTAGG(name, ',') 
              WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name) AS "Departments" 
FROM   name_and_dept 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (name, '^[A-Pa-p_]') --this will return 'nath'
GROUP  BY dept 
ORDER  BY dept; 

--second pass: names starting with "Q" through "Z"
SELECT dept, LISTAGG(name, ',') 
              WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name) AS "Departments" 
FROM   name_and_dept 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (name, '^[Q-Zq-z_]') --this will return 'shil' and 'sri'
GROUP  BY dept 
ORDER  BY dept;
```

Not the most elegant solution. Perhaps if you explain your intent with the result set, I'll be able to provide a better suggestion.

Comment: suppose we have  a department with student more then 10000 student then  LISTAGG limitation will 
fail as 4000 char will exceed for student name and we need to send it to Front end so that they can separate the data 
based on "," and each row will be based on unique dept 
Dept1 - sri,shil........
Dept2 - nath,.....
Dept3 - Ray,Garry,Raul.........

Answer (score 1):

Try XMLAGG with XMLELEMENT as like mentioned in below query.
It helps to overcome problem of 4000 char.

```
SELECT dept, to_clob(xmlagg (xmlelement (e, name|| ',')).extract ('//text   ()')) AS "Departments" 
  FROM   name_and_dept 
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (name, '^[A-Pa-p_]') --this will return 'nath'
 GROUP  BY dept 
 ORDER  BY dept;
```

For more info please check https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions215.htm
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions220.htm

Hope this will help you!